# C#: socket is destroyed when closing application

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a cash loading machine where through port 8092 it listens for instructions to process. From my application when I send instructions connecting to the socket, as we see in the following code.

[image]

Sending and receiving the socket response closes the application and also destroys the socket. (when I query netstat -n it shows 127.0.01:8092 in FAIL_WAIT2 state). Is there a way to not destroy this socket so that it remains listening? Since it is used from another application.

I already tried removing the client.Close() and stream.Close() lines of code but it still destroys the socket.

Comment: Please past your code in the question, don't use screenshots.

Comment: It's unclear what the expectation or even the question is. The code explicitly closes and disposes the TcpClient after receiving a response

Comment: You would typically continuously read from the socket in a loop. Either on a thread or using async/await. But if you do not have any special reason to use raw TCP I would recommend a higher level protocol that can send and receive *messages*. That will most likely be both easier to use and more reliable. TCP is a fairly low level protocol, and you need to know how to use it correctly.

Comment: I'd say the problem lies with the server / software listening on port 8092. A client should be able to create a new socket, send data, receive data, and close the socket connection to the server without stopping the server from listening for new connections. Unless the client is sending a command that is causing the server to stop listening.

Comment: If the problem is that the server is no longer listening after the client has disconnected, then one need to fix this in the server - no client side fix will do this. If the expectation is that the client exchanges multiple command+response sequences with the server on the same TCP connection, then there need to be a clearly defined application protocol which supports this and which need to be implemented in the client. TCP itself provides only a bytestream, no message semantic.

Comment: On Windows, the following api for socket sharing exists: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/shared-sockets-2. There may be an alternative for Unix although I haven’t looked yet.

Comment: cash loading machine? - i want to have this machine)